# what does the wildcard expression mean in command ss?

Tags: iproute, ss

```
ss -lnt

State    Recv-Q    Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
LISTEN   0         128           127.0.0.53%lo:53               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:22                  [::]:*
LISTEN   0         128                       *:80                     *:*
```

I got this after performing the command `ss`. I only know that `0.0.0.0` is a wildcard for any IP address. However, I can't find any info about `[::]` and `*:80`.

Can you give me some info about that?

Comment: The caption tells you: "any port".

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with *Address* columns:

- `0.0.0.0` is not a wildcard for *any ip address*. It is a wildcard for **any ipv4 address**.
- `[::]` is a wildcard for **any ipv6 address**.
- `*` is a wildcard for **any ip address** (both ipv4 and ipv6).

On the other side, in *Port* columns:

- `*` is a wildcard for *any port*.

In your example:

The second line means than a program is listening, on local port 22 on any local ipv4 address, for a connection from any source port, from any ipv4 address.

```
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*
```

The third line means than a program is listening, on local port 22 on any local ipv6 address, for a connection from any source port, from any ipv6 address.

```
LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:22                  [::]:*
```

Note that a line as follows is *functionally* equivalent to the sum of the 2nd and 3rd line of your example. The difference is *probably* that your ssh daemon called two times the `listen` system call, one time for each class of ip address (ipv4 and ipv6).

```
LISTEN   0         128                       *:22                     *:*
```

The forth line of your example shows that your web server daemon called `listen` once, for both classes of IP address simultaneously.

```
LISTEN   0         128                       *:80                     *:*
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what any local address means?
is LocalAddress is not system's IP address?

Comment: what does it mean it it contain system IP & if other than current system IP

Comment: what does it mean it it contain system IP & if other than current system IP